# webview- window.getselection() value is coming null

Tags: android, webview

I am working on an android application,which has a `WebView`. in this web view when i select the html text and perform any action the `window.getSelection()` is coming `null`.

One javascript method `window.getSelection()` doesn't return the selected text from WebView every time. Many developers raised issues to Google for this but no solutions. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36925404

I tried all possible option to get the selection object like

`window.getSelection(); window.doument.getSelection(); document.getSelection(); EReader.Selection.Range.getCurrentRange();`

Do you have any suggestions?